# What is a ".marvel-20XX.XX.XX" named index that is created in Elastic Search?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

When I to the URL http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices I get like around 20 indices where only 4 have been created my me. All are named like:

`yellow open .marvel-20XX.XX.XX 1 1  50712 0  51.2mb  51.2mb`.

Would it be right if I delete those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are indexes created my [Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/index.html). You can delete them, if you don't want the history of your cluster Marvel offers you.